# Python RegexHelp

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have an sentence and want to run the regex on it, to match a word.

Test Inputs :

```
This is about CHG6784532
Starting CHG4560986.
```

Code Snippet:

```
 regVal = re.compile(r"(CHG\w+)")
 for i in text:
     if regVal.search(i):
         print(i)
```

Desired Output:

```
  CHG4560986 ( NOT CHG4560986.)
```

The output the for the first input is apt, it prints "CHG6784532" but the second prints "CHG4560986.",I tried adding ^ $ to the regex but still its not helping. Is there something I am missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `text` is a string variable (if it is a list use `" ".join(text)` instead of `text` in the code below) and then you may use

```
import re
text="This is about CHG6784532\nStarting CHG4560986."
regVal = re.compile(r"CHG\w+")
res = regVal.findall(text)
print(res)
# =>  ['CHG6784532', 'CHG4560986']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F9Z3sB).

**Details**

- `regVal = re.compile(r"CHG\w+")` - the `regVal` variable is declared that holds the `CHG\w+` pattern: it matches `CHG` and then 1+ word chars
- `res = regVal.findall(text)` finds all the matching substrings in `text` variable and saves them in `res` variable